# I am not able to get text field value in to next tab viewController. I am using TabBarController with two tabs

Tags: iphone, tabs, uitabbarcontroller, uitextfield

I have a `TabBarController` with two tabs; first is `InputViewController` and second one is `TableviewController`.

Input view controller has two text fields when I enter the text, after that I want to receive that text filed value in to `TableviewController` (in the next tab). It does not receive the value.

Comment: do u have any action button, which tells textfield entry is over? and where you are maintaining the array list for loading into table?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this concept.....
Declare two variables in Second tab that is Tableviewcotroller..
For exa..

```
NSString *strname;
NSString *straddr;
```

@property and @synthesize both...

Now, in your **InputViewCotroller**tab, create and initialize object of TableViewcotroller, using this object, access these varibles. Like, you want to get values of textfields.

```
Tableviewcotroller *objTable = ........
objTable.strname = self.textName.text;
objTable.straddr = self.txtAddr.text;
```

Implement this concept in your project...Hope this helps you...:)

Comment: i tried with that but i not able to get. i am used TabBarController with two tabs first one is InputViewController anther one is TableviewController. how to pass one tab to another tab. thats i am asking.

Comment: What do you want to pass from one tab to another?

Answer (score -1):

What ever value you have in input view controller like

```
  NSString*text1=textbox1.text;
  NSString*text2=textbox2.tex;
```

In the method where you are moving to next view you should pass the value to the table view controller like this

```
DetailViewController*tblViewController=[[DetailViewController alloc]init];
NSString*textValue1=text1;

tblViewController.textValue1=textValue;
```

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tblViewController];

you should alos have textValue NSString in tableView controller also to assign value